# im trying to query the id created from using push() in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to get the key that i used to push information to my table. Is there any other way to JUST get the key itself.

i am trying to get the red marked key
[image: i am trying to get the red marked key]

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

 for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// try to get ID
        }
 }}
```

this is what i keep on getting

[image: this is what i keep on getting]

is there any other possible way on how i could get the red mark, directly?

Comment: Make a reference to the firebase database location and call `getKey();` on it

Comment: That depends on how you connect this `onDataChange` to the database. Please make sure your question includes a [minimal **complete** verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
  DatabaseReference bdRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Lobby").orderBy("lobbyname").equalTo("admin lobby");

 bdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), child.getKey().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// try to get ID

    }
}
```

Comment: If provided answer solved your problem, you can simply mark as answer to help others looking for similar solution